# Full Calendar advice for retrieving information from a database

Tags: mysql, jsp, fullcalendar

Im using Full calendar to build a timetable that schedules around the users day to day activities. I am (trying) to pull values down from a mysql database and be able to insert them into the table. I am using jsp for this and i was wondering if anyone has any advice or a good structure to how i approach this? Im not looking for code or anything but just advice. How would I go about say getting the values from the database to the jsp and then onto the table?

Answer (score 0):

I am here because I want to learn jsp. me not being the expert, I would say,

you need a database to store the dates and the events and you have managed to read the data and push the data on to the mysql database which is a good start.

Industry standard on interacting with database in the java world is hibernate(http://www.javatpoint.com/hibernate-tutorial), but it has steep learning curve.

on the client side jquery or someother javascript framework you have tons of it these days.

I do not know whether I solved your queries but it would be good if you ask queries in a way

I have done this ? 
what I can do better ? with examples.

good luck :)